# Стили элементов управления WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Мое окно]

Создал класс, который наследую от Form. Когда вывожу его на экран элементы управления имеют не такой вид, как если бы делал окно через конструктор. У кнопки нет эффекта изменения цвета по наведению. Нет синих границ у TextBox-а, когда он активен и др. На скриншоте хорошо все видно. 
Как исправить этот дефект?

Comment: И еще подскажите как убрать треугольничек в правом нижнем углу

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вызвать

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

перед

```
Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте чуть больше пояснений к вашему ответу.